# Network Photo Application cache (Nimbus)

Tags: ios, caching, nimbus-ios

In the Network Photo application sample from Nimbus, when I return to the table (to choose from where I want to download photos beging Facebook or Dribbble), the previous photos I saw and were in cache, are cleared from it. Is there a way to prevent this?

For instance:

- I enter in the album A, I downloaded 50 photos to cache.
- I enter in the album B, I downloaded 50/60 photos.
- When I re-enter the album A, I want to use the ones I have in cache.

My scenario is: Multiple Projects (Data Sources), when I go from one to another, if I have been there already, I want it to use my internal cache.

Most important: Is it possible to save it for the iPhone's internal memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photos are being removed from memory when you leave the photo controller because it is the photo controller that instantiates the image caches for the photos. If you would like to keep the photos in memory beyond the existence of the photo controller then you will need to create some form of a global image in-memory cache within which you store the photos.

As for whether you can save the photos to disk, I believe that the examples use ASIHTTPRequest which uses a disk cache for the images. This will automatically cache images to disk so that even if they are removed from memory they won't be downloaded from the network again. This can still cause the images to take a second to load because loading large photos from disk isn't as fast as using them from an in-memory cache.

Comment: I don't need them to stick in memory, but rather in the disk. I don't think they are being loaded from the disk again, because if I turn internet off they will not be loaded...